# How to invoke time command with parameter and same behavior as without parameter?

Tags: shell, time, ksh

I want to specify the format for time, but it behaves differenty:

```
$ time echo hehe | sleep 1        

real    0m1.03s
user    0m0.00s
sys     0m0.00s

$ time -p echo hehe | sleep 1     

real 0.00
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

So if I provide any switch to time, it will behave differently:

- in first case the time measured the whole commnad's time (with pipe)
- in the second case it measured only the echo's time

How can I specify -p and get the result from the first run?

Comment: Why do you have to pipe-line `echo`'s output to time? Did you mean it to run one after the other?

Comment: I have a more meaningful task to do, but this example shows my problem with the time command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. In ksh, `time` can time a pipeline, while `time -p` can only time the first stage.

- POSIX `time` on a pipeline is undefined. `ksh`'s implementation chooses to time the entire pipeline.
- ksh `time` does not support `-p` or any other flags, and will delegate to external `time` if it's invoked with any flags.
- external `time` (e.g. `/usr/bin/time`) can only operate on the first stage of a pipeline (because pipelines are a shell construct and require shell cooperation).

Either switch to a shell that does allow this (like bash), or rewrite to something that external `time` can work with, such as a single stage with `sh -c` that internally runs a pipeline:

```
time -p sh -c 'echo hehe | sleep 1'
```